# WAMP 2.5 | The remote device or resource won't accept the connection

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I've recently installed WAMP Server 2.5 on a Hyper-V virtual machine that is running Windows 7 x64.

When I try to access localhost it will not work. Running a test with Network Diag returned the following error: *"The remote device or resource won't accept the connection"*

I have installed the required Visual C++ Redistributable packages (and then some: vcredist_x86_2008, vcredist_x86_2010, vcredist_x64_2010, vcredist_x64_2012)

Apache error log:

```
[Mon Nov 16 12:19:11.305674 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2964:tid 380] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Mon Nov 16 12:19:13.385104 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2700:tid 304] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Mon Nov 16 12:19:14.314065 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2964:tid 380] AH00430: Parent: Child process 2700 exited successfully.
```

The PHP error log and the MySQL logs are empty.

I've also ran a `netstat -a -b` command to see what's listening to port :80 and there was nothing.

If I run Test port 80 from Apache it returns `Your port 80 is not actually used.`

When I go to Apache > Service > Install Service the result returned is

```
Your port 80 is available, Install will proceed.
Press Enter to continue...
```

Any idea why is this not working? It worked fine when I first installed it, then I just restarted the services and it won't start them anymore.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I am providing here worked for me:

1. go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`
2. copy the file host to your desktop
3. open it and ensure that line:

   `# ::1             localhost`

   has `\` in front of `#`, like:

   `\#    ::1             localhost`
4. save it
5. move this file back to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and replace it